# Jetty 9.3.6 throwing ClassNotFoundException for org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException

Tags: eclipse, jetty, classnotfoundexception

I am running a Jetty 9.3.6 webapp. In my production environment, I sometimes see an EofException. In my dev environment I get a ClassCastException for this class (see below).

In both environments, I start jetty using "-jar start.jar". What is going wrong in my dev environment?

WEB-INF/lib contents, and --verbose:class and --list-config output are here: 
http://pastebin.com/Ncc5DJNu

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/io/EofException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.ensureInstance(ServletHolder.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.ensureInstance(ServletHolder.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The most common cause is that you have multiple different versions of the various Jetty jar files present.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible. I installed the same installation in both places and never touched the unpacked files. The start.jars have the same md5sum, and in both environments, for all the jar files whose name specifies a version, the suffix is -9.3.6.v20151106.jar.

Comment: Additional information: I turned on -verbose:class and can see the class being loaded: "[Loaded org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException from file:/opt/jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106/lib/jetty-io-9.3.6.v20151106.jar]". This is _before_ the request that triggers the EofException, (i.e., before the exception is thrown).

Comment: Edit your question, run `-jar start.jar --list-config` and report the output. also list your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory contents in the question.

Comment: Edited, thank you.